# CSS - Border with a 90º curve at top

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website that will looks like the GNU/Linux terminal. For that, I'm creating a blog page, which will have some boxes, where each box is a blog post. This is the boilerplate HTML code of each blog post:

```
<div class="post">
    <h3 class="post-title">Title</h3>
    <span class="post-content">
        The awesome content goes here.
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to insert a border on each of these boxes, but instead of inserting a regular border, I would like to break on top and make a curve of 90º degrees around both sides of the title, like this:

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGXpN.jpg)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.post {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="post">
    <h3 class="post-title">Title</h3>
    <span class="post-content">
        The awesome content goes here.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creating a normal border on the div then setting a border on both sides of the h3 was pretty smart, however, making that way, I could not have a overflow around the border of the div, because if you take a look at the image, the border are actually inside the div, not on its edge. So, I managed it by putting the border in the pseudo-element :before of div, by making that, I was able to put margins around div. Also, I defined the background of h3 as the same color as the div and moved it in a way that it overlapped the top margin of div, making all exactly the same as seen in the image.

Comment: @TheoneLucas I have edited my answer to include an extra wrap outside the box. Psuedo element works fine as well.

Comment: Really thanks for the wrap suggestion, and for the whole answer, your tricky of setting a border on the h3 and using it to overlap the div border was very smart, simple and elegant, thanks.

Comment: @TheoneLucas Happy to help.